# Как проверить, является ли файл пустым?

Tags: python

Как проверить файл на отсутствие в нем символов?

Comment: Думаю нет смысла дублировать вопросы и ответы: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507808/how-to-check-whether-a-file-is-empty-or-not

Comment: Ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2507808/2110496

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>import os
>>os.stat("file").st_size == 0
True
```